# How do I get value from the custom component Floating Label?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

There is a custom component called Floating Label, which I found from the list of NativeScript examples, 
I tried getting the values from  component by giving them id, and I tried to use var c = page.getViewById("cisc").text; and put the value inside a variable, but that did not work, if I console.log the var that contains the getViewbyId("cisc"), it would output this in console.log(c);
StackLayout@file:///app/components/float-label/FloatLabel.xml:1:1;

[Floating Label](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=oSksgv&v=26)

Comment: Where exactly you have the code `page.getViewById("txtl")`, I don't see it in your Playground. Please share the exact sample code you are using.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=oSksgv&v=26

Comment: Updated the question and link, 
It has been hours I cannot get user input value.

Comment: @Manoj, Is that good now? I updated. Now what is the solution (with code sample)?

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely expected, the id will be assigned to the root element of your custom component, in your case it's a `StackLayout`. In order to get the `text` you have to do `page.getViewById("cisc").getChildAt(1).text`.

Comment: That works, but one very big problem, if I input an Arabic or Kurdish name, it gets the value like this 'Ø§Ø§ÙØ§".
Not in this playground, but in NativeScript Sidekick, 
I did use page.getViewById("cisc").getChildAt(1).text
If I write English character, it is fine, but Arabic characters, it gets value and give me this unusual characters Ø§Ø§ÙØ§ (this changes to similar unusual character if I input different test).

Note: I use a custom font for my NativeScript app, called "Noto Kufi Arabic", because it supports Kurdish letters, beside Arabic.

Comment: I don't use Sidekick much, I suspect that may be simple character encoding issue on Sidekick console. Try setting the value to a Label or show it on Alert to test it.

Comment: I don't think this problem is related to Sidekick, but rather to whole NativeScript.
How do I fix this problem? How do I fix this encoding issue as you say?

I will accept your answer and vote you up on stackoverflow if this issue solved,

Comment: I alerted it, it shows the Arabic input name correctly, but it is saved on the Couchbase database like Ø§Ø§ÙØ§
and the console.log is still something like Ø§Ø§ÙØ§

Comment: I also queried couchbase database and it looks it is stored as Ø§Ø§ÙØ§

Comment: It must be something to do with your character set encoding on your couch db.

Comment: No! Understand that Before floatinglabel, I was using TextField, and when I entered an Arabic name, I could console.log(name) it and it displayed very well, and it was stored inside couchbase very well.

Comment: Still you are using a TextField for enter the values only that it's wrapped into a reusable layout. If you think the problem is just the floating label, please submit both versions of Playground, the one where it works with Arabic and the one where it doesn't.

Comment: Playground has no issues at all, 
Here is my final playground of floatinglabel
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=oSksgv&v=27

Comment: There is no both versions, because it always console logged the arabic fine

Comment: If I set the value to Label it displays fine, 
So, the problem might be Developers tools in nativescript sidekick, the console of developers tools might not be able to display the characters well,
Is there a function in nativescript to make the variable UTF or unicode????

Comment: I opened an issue which I clarified better https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/354

Do u  know any solutions?